# How can I solve this recurrent equation word problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

My wife has bought a flock of hens to have some eggs for this year’s Easter and
I have to feed them. On day 0, they got 10 kgs of wheat, the next day (day 1),
I gave them 14 kgs. Since then, I give them the average of the previous two days
increased by 1 kg in even numbered days and decreased by 1 kg in odd
numbered days.

I have $$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}2 +(-1)^n$$ but I don't know how to proceed or if it's correct.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. But where would you wanna proceed? Also, pls. use mathjax. (See my edits)

Comment: How can I solve it ?

Comment: I believe it has already been solved. It is not asking you to *solve* anything in particular, but merely asking you to write it out in an expression. I guess you can define $a_n$ for $n\geqslant 2$ because we denote by $a_n$ the $n^{\text{th}}$ day, and there exists Day $0$, follows that $\exists a_0$. In symbols, you can have that the equation is equal to $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 2}$ by definition, instead of $a_n$..... Reading the question again, do you want to find the pattern of kgs of wheat given? Well, you already wrote the formula. Just substitute $n = 2$ with $a_0 = 10$ and $a_1 = 14$.

Comment: Solve *what*?  The word "problem" doesn't ask you to do any thing.  You've correctly stated $a_n$ as a the average of the last two days plus or minus one.  Does the question ask you what a general formula (not recursive)?  Do it ask you if ammount of grain fed reaches a consistant value?  What?  You didn't ask any question.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence converges to $o(a_0,a_1)$ for the odd numbers and to $o(a_0,a_1)+2$ for the even numbers, where $$o(a_0,a_1)=\frac{a_0+2a_1-2}3.\tag 1$$

To be honest, I don't know why.

**EDIT**

The only reason behind the assertion above is that if the odd day numbers and the even day numbers converge then the following equation has to hold

$$o=\frac{a_0+2a_1-2}3=\frac{o+e}2-1=\frac{\frac{a_o+2a_1-2}3+\frac{a_o+2a_1-2}3+2}2-1$$
and it does.

**EDIT 2**

But to say "it does" is not enough. Because the following identities hold as well

$$o=\frac{\frac{\alpha a_o+\beta a_1-2}3+\frac{\alpha a_o+\beta a_1-2}3+2}2-1$$
for $o=\frac{\alpha a_0+\beta a_1-2}3.$

Yet the limit IS $(1)$!